# Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I am using Mac OS X 10.9.5 with git version 2.1.2. Entering
    git push
I receive:
    Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
I have run
    sudo xcodebuild -license
and entered 'agree', but the problem remains.
Opening Xcode there is no licence agreement appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating all mac port programs git works again. I do not understand the downvotes, in my opinion this information may save time for others.

Answer (score 5):

`sudo xcodebuild -license` will show you the license of Xcode.You have to agree its terms and condition at the end or you can just run the command given below.

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Answer (score 3):

in terminal, run 'sudo xcodebuild -license' and then agree to the terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a private remote repo. make sure you accept the license agreement at the server as well. it took me weeks to find the error is coming from the server side as I was using ssh to connect

Answer (score 0):

try running XCode standalone to say OK to license agreement for iOS7 update.

Comment: Does Xcode standalone mean to start it from Applications? I have already tried it.